# Supporting both file downloads and async postbacks in GridView within UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, http-headers, updatepanel

I have an ASP.NET webforms app with a page which contains a GridView control listing documents the user has uploaded. I have a LinkButton in one of the columns that causes the GridView to raise a RowCommand event. The CommandArgument of the LinkButton is the document ID and I execute the following code:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-type", document.FileType);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename=\"{document.FileName}\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", document.FileContent.Length.ToString());
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.BinaryWrite(document.FileContent);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

This was working great but I also wanted to support paging in my GridView so I set AllowPaging = true and wrapped the GridView in an update panel. It seems that when I do this it stops working and I get this following exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException

Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.

at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseInternalWrapper.set_ContentType(String value)
   at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.RenderPageCallback(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control pageControl)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I want to do an asynchronous postback for the GridView paging but I guess a regular postback for the RowCommand. I don't have any triggers set in my Update Panel but ChildrenAsTriggers = true.

Typically I use an HttpHandler for file downloads but I don't think that's an option here as I don't want to pass arguments on the QueryString due to security reasons. I like being able to have the page's code-behind do the work.

Is it possible to make this work or am I going to have to stop using the UpdatePanel and disable paging?

Comment: Since you've stated that `UpdatePanel` is used, try handling `OnInit` event of the linkbutton and add these lines on code behind: `var linkbuttonID = sender as LinkButton; ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(linkbuttonID);`. Better to show both related markup and code behind too.

Comment: Tetsuya - I saw this in another post but thought there might have been a different way to do this. Unfortunately there is not. I tried your code instead and it works and I can still use async paging with my GridView. Thank you.